# JAVA - Program functions as input output, input output; want to make it so program functions as input input, output, output, respectively

Tags: java, input, output

I've just started learning Java, and I wanted to overcome a hurdle that showed up when trying to create a Java program for this 'problem'. This is the problem I had to create a program for:

*Tandy loves giving out candies, but only has n candies. For the ith person she gives a candy to, she gives i candies to that person. For example, she first gives Randy 1 candy, then gives Pandy 2 candies, then Sandy 3. Given n, how many people can she give candies to?*

*Input Format

The first line is an integer x, denoting the number of test cases.
The next x lines will contain a single positive integer, n.*

*SAMPLE INPUT

2

1

5*

*Output Format

x lines, with each line containing a single integer denoting the number of people Tandy can give candies to.*

*SAMPLE OUTPUT

1

2*

To solve this problem, I created a program, and it functions well, but it doesn't match what the problem is asking for.
The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PRB1CandyGame {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner cases = new Scanner(System.in);
        int repeats = cases.nextInt();
        while (repeats > 0)
        {
            int x = cases.nextInt();
            int i = 1;
            for(i = 1; x-i>=0; i++) 
            {
                x = x-i;    
            }   
            System.out.println(i-1);
            repeats--;
        }
    }  
}
```

(Sorry if the code is messy!)

My code takes in the number of 'cases' and then that's how many times I can enter in a number of candies to get the number of people it can provide. However, my program takes the number of candies and then outputs the number of people right after, while I want it to take in *all* the inputs (number of inputs is based on what the user enters for the number of cases), and then output *all* the values, rather than what I have. If you can explain to me how I can do that, it will help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: *I want it to take in all the inputs*  consider passing them as command line parameters instead

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want your input to be stored some where first before you start processing answers then output all answers at once.

I Honestly think the question wants you to process each test case as input then output the result. So you're presently on the right track.

But if you want to get all inputs then process each one then output, use an array since you know the size of the test case. You will also need to create an array of same size for output then process each ith item in the input array and store each result in the same ith position in the output array.

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail, because I have no idea on how to use an array. [I just started learning java!]

Comment: I suggest you read about arrays in places like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm  An array is used to store a fixed collection of items of the same data type. So an array can contain [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].... To create an array, write: int [] array = new int [sizeOfArray]; to input into it you use array[ith] = 1;..... The link explains better